# Printing(on paper) the values of html textboxes within a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, printing

I have an html form with a large number of various textboxes containing data.  I have a button the bottom of that page that says Print.  Now I do not want to print the entire page.  I want only the values of certain textboxes to be printed out on paper when that button is pressed.

Javascript is the route I was looking for...

Can someone just give me the basic code to print out the content of one box?

one example please

*******************EDIT*******************************

It appears as if my question was poorly worded.  What I want to do is grab data from these html input text boxes and load it up on a new page after the print button is pressed and print that new page.  I want to know how to grab that data from the boxes, and paste it on the popup page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your page header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="view.css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print"/>
```

Now keep your standard CSS in view.css. In print.css add styling to format/hide/show elements you want to see on paper.

Comment: What exactly is vague about that?

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this with a print stylesheet.

You can hide the elements you don't want, rearrange them however you wish and style them all specifically for the printout.

```
@media print {
  /* style sheet for print goes here */
}
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

Comment: Quick question:  do I still link with it with javascript, and where do I list the fields I want/or don't want?

Comment: No need for JavaScript, @Daniel Gruszczyk describes how to link to external stylesheets in his answer. Then it's just a case of defining CSS rules - @fin1te gives a simple example of that.

Answer (score 2):

You can acheive this with CSS using a print style sheet.

In the style sheet, just hide everything apart from the text boxes

```
* { display: none }

textarea { display: block }
```

See here for details http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml